# Adding arraylist elements one by one

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylist named "Nama" and "Tambah". Here's the elements contained in both of them:

```
ArrayList NAMA:[Upi, Qori, Wulan, Indah]
ArrayList LENGKAP:[Meidina, Aisyah, Febiarty, Windari]
```

i want to add every elements of "Nama" to arraylist "Lengkap" one by one. So the result will be like this:

```
Arraylist LENGKAP: [Meidina, Aisyah, Febiart, Windari, Upi]

Arraylist LENGKAP: [Meidina, Aisyah, Febiart, Windari, Qori]

Arraylist LENGKAP: [Meidina, Aisyah, Febiart, Windari, Wulan]

Arraylist LENGKAP: [Meidina, Aisyah, Febiart, Windari, Indah]
```

So, in every iteration the size of arraylist LENGKAP will remain the same (5). Anyone have idea how to code it?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with? Can't you just remove the last element, then add the new element?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html Read and find what you need.

Comment: Just use a `For` loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @Carcigenicate then at the first iteration it will remove the last original elements of arraylist LENGKAP.

Comment: @LutfiMeidina The just don't remove when the index is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go through your first list and make a new list from `your second list` plus `the current element of the first list`:

**Solution 1:** Re-using the same list

```
for(String s : NAMA) {
  if(LENGKAP.size() == 4) {
    LENGKAP.add(s);
  } else {
    LENGKAP.set(4, s);
  }
  System.out.println(LENGKAP);
}
```

**Solution 2:** Creating a new list at each iteration

```
for(String s : NAMA) {
  List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(LENGKAP);
  l.add(s);
  System.out.println(l);
}
```

Both solutions output:

```
[Meidina, Aisyah, Febiarty, Windari, Upi]
[Meidina, Aisyah, Febiarty, Windari, Qori]
[Meidina, Aisyah, Febiarty, Windari, Wulan]
[Meidina, Aisyah, Febiarty, Windari, Indah]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [`ArrayList#set(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) and replace the last element with the index `arraylist.size() -1` while iterating over it.